# Uninstalling Firebase from app, went too far?

Tags: android, firebase, uninstallation, firebase-console

I connected my app to Firebase and decided later I wanted to undo it all. So I removed firebase references from my Gradle files, ran this instead:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-iid'
}
```

went to the Firebase console, and used the DELETE THIS APP function. I also deleted the project from the Firebase console.

However now I received an email saying that my app is being removed from the developer console itself as a result of this action? Did I overdo it somewhere?

All I want to do is remove Firebase from my app completely. I don't want to delete anything else past that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to remove the dependencies and clear the application cache on the device

You overdid it by even touching the Firebase developer console

Comment: I didn't touch the developer console though, I was only in the firebase console here https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Same thing. Let me rephrase, you didn't need to open a website

Comment: That doesn't make sense though; why does removing something from your Firebase console imply removing the entire app itself from the developer console?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact terminologies here, but my point is that if you only want the device itself to not have Firebase, you didn't need to open that page at all

Comment: What are my options at this point? Move all my code over to a new project / package name and reupload as a new app?

Comment: I mean, you deleted Firebase, right? Wasn't that your question? Why are you needing to move or upload  anything?

Comment: No, my question is what my options now, now that my project is slated for deletion

Comment: You have to create a new Firebase project... I don't think there is any other option